# Playing sound from a sound system a distance away

Tags: audio

I work at an event facility. There is no house sound system so the sound is handled by whatever the various DJs bring in. The DJs change with each event.

What doesent change is that I am in my back room for the event. It would be helpful for me to hear what ever is going through the sound system(speeches, announcements, music, ect).

I am looking to place a speaker in my room. I have three questions:

1. Is the DJ likely to object to me having another speaker to connect to his system?
2. What sort of connection would best for this? Component cable? 3.5mm?
3. (The big question) How should this system work? It is probably too difficult to run wires, so some sort of wireless system? Maybe just a radio transmitter with a boombox? There may be a wireless network if that would make it easier.

[image: event layout]

Comment: Dosen't really feel on topic - no computers anywhere in sight. Its a *cool* question, but not a good fit for SU.

Comment: maybe it belongs to [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Comment: er, probably not - dosn't feel like a good fit there. There's no UX stuff in the question either. Even [AVP](http://avp.stackexchange.com/) dosen't feel right, and thats the closest i can think of

Comment: I was afraid it would be off topic, but I couldn't find a better SE, and frankly, if anybody would have an answer, it would be the people on here. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2):

Given that there is no in-house PA, you can't expect that everyone's rig is going to have a spare output, and if it does it's going to be a hassle for you to hook in.  You'd need a range of different options, and it's going to hamper your clients while they're trying to get ready for a show.

I would suggest your best bet is a closed microphone circuit.  Perhaps a little condenser mic mounted on the ceiling in the main area, with a cable run back to your work area into an active stage monitor (if you need volume) or into a computer.  How big a distance are you talking?  My gut is you need about 50m of cable.  You'd want a properly balanced mic cable and probably a cheap phantom-powered condenser.

US$35 for a mic: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/747382-REG/Nady_CM_90_CM_90_Cardioid_Condenser.html

Maybe about US$70 for a 150' / 45m cable...

Some kind of ceiling mount that can fit a microphone clip...  Or you could just hang the mic from the end of the cable.

US$150 for an active monitor with phantom powered mic preamp seems okay...  http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/behringer-eurolive-b205d-active-pa-monitor-speaker

Well, that's what I'd do if I ran a venue =)  I'm usually on the other side of things, playing in bands.  Anyway, good luck!